# ¿Funciona el comodin unicode \p{L} en una regex para PHP sobre Linux?

Tags: php, linux, regex, php7, unicode

Estoy tratando de escribir una expresión regular en PHP para validar el nombre de unas comunidades para insertarlo en una base de datos, los cuales pueden tener la siguiente estructura `[palabra][espacio][palabra][espacio][palabra][...]`.

Por ejemplo `[Ojo][ ][de][ ][Agua][ ][de][ ][los][ ][Maldonado]`. Como son comunidades cuyos nombres incluyen acentos y la letra ñ se escribió la siguiente expresión regular

```
/^\p{L}+\s?\p{L}*\s?\p{L}*\s?\p{L}*\s?\p{L}*\s?\p{L}*$/
```

La manera en que se usa es la siguiente:

```
mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');

function validarNombre($nombre,$tabla){
$nombreValido=FALSE;
if (strcmp($tabla, "Comunidades")==0) {
            if (strlen($nombre)>=3 && strlen($nombre)<=50){
                if (preg_match('/^\p{L}+\s?\p{L}*\s?\p{L}*\s?\p{L}*\s?\p{L}*\s?\p{L}*$/m', $nombre)) {
                    $nombreValido = TRUE;
                }
            }else{
                $nombreValido = FALSE;
            }
        }
        
        return $nombreValido;
    }
```

Realizando pruebas en [regex101.com](https://regex101.com) esta expresión regular funciona, si embargo cuando se usa en el script de php que uso en la máquina donde se está desarrollando palabras como Güilotas, Puruándiro, Núñez, Carácuaro, etc no coinciden con el patrón dado.

Por ejemplo, usando un script de pruebas se hace lo siguiente:

```
include 'validar.php';
    validarNombre($nombre="PURUARÁN", $tabla="Comunidades");
    validarNombre($nombre="TURICATO", $tabla="Comunidades");
    validarNombre($nombre="GÜILOTAS", $tabla="Comunidades");
    validarNombre($nombre="NÚÑEZ", $tabla="Comunidades");
```

El resultado es una pantalla en blanco.

Nota: El entorno que se usa es PHP 7.4 sobre ubuntu. Además se hizo prueba en una máquina con Windows 10 y da los mismos resultados.

Comment: ¿Qué codificación hay en el entorno donde está fallando el REGEX?

Comment: @A.Cedano ¿Te refieres en qué función lo estoy usando? Si es así, uso la función preg_match().

Comment: No. Me refiero a la codificación (si es UTF-8, ISO, etc). En tu entorno PHP (servidor) y en tu entorno de salida o cliente (html, consola, archivo) etc.

Comment: Ya revisé y el set de caracteres por defecto es UTF-8, se modificó el archivo php.ini para activar la extensión mbstring y además se usó la función mb_internal_encoding() para establecer el set de caracteres a UTF-8. Con estos cambios sigue sin funcionar.

Comment: La codificación tiene varios niveles: 1. Origen de los datos cuando son tomados (un archivo de texto, documento, el navegador, etc); 2. Contexto en que se manipulan los datos, en este caso sería PHP, y en ese contexto tomarías los datos de 1 para pasarlos a 3 o a 4...; 3.. Destino de los datos en caso de necesitar almacenarlos (base de datos, otro archivo, etc); 4. Salida de los datos (por pantalla, en un archivo,etc). Como ves, podrían ser al menos 4 niveles, y debes verificar la codificación en todos ellos.

Comment: He leído que se debe tener el mismo set de caracteres tanto en el documento HTML como en los scripts de PHP y en la base de datos. Para todos ellos se ha definido el mismo set de caracteres. Como podrás notar en el código que puse arriba (edité la pregunta) solo estoy tratando de validar nombres de comunidades que tienen nombres con acentos y la ñ a través de una expresión regular, esta expresión ya fue probada en [regex101.com](https://www.regex101.com) pero no funciona en mi máquina ni la de los compañeros.

Comment: He probado tu código en rextester.com y funciona correctamente con los ejemplos que has puesto (devuelve TRUE o FALSE según el caso). Si en tu entorno no funciona significa que hay problemas de codificación, sea en el ámbito de PHP, sea en el ámbito de consola (menos probable). Lo cierto es que en algún punto está el problema y tampoco deberá ser tan complicado encontrarlo haciendo las depuraciones adecuadas.

Comment: @A.Cedano ya he logrado hacer que funcione, me faltaba la librería mbstring y, como mencionabas, establecer el set de caracteres en UTF-8 en el archivo de configuración de PHP.

Comment: Me alegro de que lo hayas resuelto. Si lo consideras útil agrega como respuesta lo que has hecho para que pueda servir a otros usuarios en un futuro con algún problema parecido.